# How to run Asynchronous service call with NSOperationQueue or performSelectorInBackground

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, background-process

I am using NSURLConnection asynchronous call to load data from server.While calling service method with performSelectorInBackground,The method gets called but NSURLConnection  does  not provide any response.I am using asynchronous call  because i have to validated authentication first.Whenever i tried service call on main thread it gives me proper data but UI gets freeze.
1) How to make asynchronous call with performSelectorInBackground
what is wrong am i doing by loading data asynchronously.

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible way though not via NSURLConnection, but it doesn't block:

```
NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];

if (self.xmlParser != nil)
{
    [self.xmlParser abortParsing];
    self.xmlParser = nil;
}

dispatch_queue_t loadQueue1 = dispatch_queue_create("loadQueue1", NULL);

// Use another thread to avoid blocking main thread

dispatch_async(loadQueue1,^{

self.xmlParser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL] autorelease];

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
[self.xmlParser setDelegate:self];


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
if (self.xmlParser != nil)
{
    [self.xmlParser  parse];
}

    });


});

dispatch_release(loadQueue1);
```

Comment: Thanks casillic but  this way i guess i can't validate for certificate authentication. I want asynchronous call but without freezing the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,after debugging the code i got the error.It is not the asynchronous call but the updating method after receiving the huge response freezes my UI.Also the NSLog that i put to print the data causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `NSURLConnection` with the asynchronous API, you don't need to use `performSelectorInBackground`. You call it from the main thread, and you set a delegate, the delegate will be called when data is coming or another event is happening, without blocking the main thread.